# EnableWindow(hWnd, false) doesn't disable keyboard input

Tags: c++, winapi

I am attempting to disable a window under certain conditions using `EnableWindow(hWnd, false);`

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291.aspx), this should "disable mouse and keyboard input to the specified window".

The problem I am seeing is that it does, in fact, disable like it says, except if the cursor is currently inside of a text box in the window and the window has the focus that does not get disabled. I was thinking of doing some sort of code to take the focus off of the window as well.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Note: The window being disabled is a binary ran via `_spawnl()`.

Comment: I think you will have to use `EnumChildWindows` to call `EnableWindow` on each child window

Comment: No, you don't need to disable every child window, disabling a parent window disables input for all child windows. However, using `EnableWindow()` across process boundaries is not a good thing to do in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a Windows feature or a bug. Either way, disabling the foreground window is not a good idea.

If you are able to modify the program you start with `_spawnl()` then that is a better solution. You could make it respond to WM_APP or something like that when you need to control it.

If it is a 3rd-party application then you are left with hacks.

You could try to change the foreground window with `SetForegroundWindow` but this will only work if you do it very soon after `_spawnl()` before your thread loses the foreground lock. Using `LockSetForegroundWindow` before `_spawnl()`  might be able to help you keep the lock longer. There are also various other hacks to change the foreground with [`AttachThreadInput`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130619-00/?p=4043) etc.

If you don't want to change the foreground I was able to come up with a workaround:

```
  ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, TEXT("Notepad"), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
  Sleep(2000);
  HWND hNP = FindWindow(TEXT("Notepad"), NULL);
  Sleep(2000); // Start typing in Notepad now...
  if (hNP)
  {
    DWORD tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hNP, NULL);
    GUITHREADINFO gti;
    gti.cbSize = sizeof(gti);
    if (tid && GetGUIThreadInfo(tid, &gti))
    {
      HWND hChild = NULL;
      if (gti.hwndFocus != hNP && gti.hwndFocus)
      {
        EnableWindow(hChild = gti.hwndFocus, false);
      }
      if (GetForegroundWindow() == hNP)
      {
        SendNotifyMessage(hNP, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_INACTIVE, NULL);
        SendNotifyMessage(hNP, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_ACTIVE, NULL);
        SendNotifyMessage(hNP, WM_SETFOCUS, NULL, NULL);
        // SendNotifyMessage(hNP, WM_NCACTIVATE, false, NULL); // Uncomment to make it look like it is inactive
      }
      EnableWindow(hNP, false);
      if (hChild)
      {
        EnableWindow(hChild, true);
      }
    }
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Done?"), NULL, MB_TOPMOST);
    SetForegroundWindow(hNP);
    PostMessage(hNP, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
  }
```

This is certainly not optimal, it leaves Notepad in a state where it looks like it is enabled but it is really not. The idea is to disable the focused child window and trigger a fake activation change and forcing the focus to change. It might not work with other applications, who knows.

If you are willing to risk a deadlock you can do this instead:

```
    DWORD tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hNP, NULL);
    GUITHREADINFO gti;
    gti.cbSize = sizeof(gti);
    if (tid && GetGUIThreadInfo(tid, &gti))
    {
      if (GetForegroundWindow() == hNP)
      {
        if (AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId(), tid, true))
        {
          SetFocus(NULL);
          AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId(), tid, false);
        }
      }
      EnableWindow(hNP, false);
    }
```

Comment: So this second part worked great, I am curious if you expand on why it would risk deadlock.

Comment: @RyanBoykin https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130607-00/?p=4143/# https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130619-00/?p=4043# etc.